# Filter a list in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a simple @foreach loop in a view that iterates over a list:

```
@foreach (var record in Model.ChangeOrder.Change_Order_Dash_List)
{
    ....
}
```

Works great!  But, depending on a boolean in the model, I may need to filter this list.  This, I am having trouble figuring out.  This is what I'm trying:

```
@{List<MCA.Models.ChangesVM.ChangeOrderInfo> Change_Order_Dash_List = new List<MCA.Models.ChangesVM.ChangeOrderInfo>();}

@if (Model.ViewChangeOrdersFromChart)
{
    Change_Order_Dash_List = Model.ChangeOrder.Change_Order_Dash_List.Where(l => l.Implement_Date == Model.ViewChangeOrdersOnDate).ToList<MCA.Models.ChangesVM.ChangeOrderInfo>();
}
else
{
   Change_Order_Dash_List = Model.ChangeOrder.Change_Order_Dash_List;
}


@foreach (var record in Change_Order_Dash_List )
{
    ....
}
```

But the results are weird.  When I render the page, the list looks to be empty.  No data is rendered to the screen. And if I set a breakpoint anywhere on the page, it is never hit.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to put everything in @{ } razor block. You have missing "}". Maybe is not rendered properly.

Comment: I thought I had.  What am I missing?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the `foreach` loop is working fine for you until you add the `@if (!Model.ViewChangeOrdersFromChart)` block?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: I am not seeing closing curly bracket from first block. Maybe you can try with single @{ ....  } razor block because you handle only C# code.

Comment: @kat1330 -- that's a typo in the copy paste while making this post.  I'll edit the OP to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (and IMO more simple) syntax to achieve this, is to merge the `if` condition into the `Where` using the `||` operator like this:

```
yourList.Where(l => !Model.ViewChangeOrdersFromChart || 
                    l.Implement_Date == Model.ViewChangeOrdersOnDate)
```

This will filter the list only when `Model.ViewChangeOrdersFromChart` is `true`.
This way you don't need the if condition at all.

Comment: Great tip!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, for whatever weird reason, this did not work:

```
@if (Model.ViewChangeOrdersFromChart)
```

but this did...

```
@if (Model.ViewChangeOrdersFromChart == true)
```